# How to find the execution time in stm32f3xx?

Tags: c, time, embedded, stm32, execution

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"
#include<time.h>

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
long int count1,count2,count,i=5;


int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();

    SystemClock_Config();

    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_TIM2_Init();
    HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);

    count1= __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim2);

    while (i)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_3,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay(50000);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_3,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_Delay(10000);       
        i--;
    } 
    count=count2-count1;
    count2= __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim2);
}
```

The code output is always 0. I am unable to obtain the count values. can anyone tell me why it is not executing? I am using STM32F303k8 microcontroller. The count values are always zero, even though it takes few minutes to execute completely!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Booma Are you serious? `while(i)` is the same as `while(i != 0)`.

Comment: @Booma while(i) is equivalent to while(i != 0)

Comment: Sorry for that. Too long time ago that I actively used C and my teaching prof always told us to use full expressions -.-

Comment: @Booma no worries...the problem with full expressions is that it is too easy to mistakenly code while(i = 0) ... which is a disaster

Comment: swap count= and count2= add a mask the size of the timer if 16 bits then count=(count2-count1)&0xFFFF; for example.

Comment: and understand your measurement is for that run/build, add or remove code dont be surprised if the time changes (add a nop or two or three to your bootstrap for example).  it is an stm32 so there is a cache in front of the flash you cant turn off, but there are times when it misses and you get the real flash exposed.

Comment: The code is incomplete, the definition of `MX_TIM2_Init()` is missing. We won't be able to help without a [MCVE].

Comment: @aja That's a nonsense argument from the early 1980s. In the late 80s compilers started to give warnings for assignment in expressions, as they should. Since then, this is a none-issue.

Comment: also note that if this takes seconds to run your prescaler should be such that the timer doesnt roll more than a full cycle otherwise you are only getting the remainder not the whole time measurement.  start with a simpler experiment, read the time, do a small delay, read the time, print/save the two time measurements and view them.   change the delay, see the time measurements change.  then do the subtract, see that that works, then get more complicated...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, count2 and count1 are uninitialized (and not clear - to me, if they are accessed by other functions. If you're lucky, they're initialized to 0, which explains why count2 and count1 are zero towards the end of the code

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
count=count2-count1;
count2= __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim2);
```

makes no sense at all, you're subtracting from `count2` before refreshing it from the timer?

It should perhaps be:

```
const uint32_t now = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim2);
count += now - last;
last = now;
```

With `uint32_t last = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim2);` before the loop.

Comment: unless you know the timer is a 32 bit timer you need a mask along with the subtract to get the correct value.  (now - last)&MASK.

Comment: @old_timer It happens to be a 32-bit timer, but I don't think it matters. Even assuming 16 bits the expression would still be valid, just as it would if the 32-bit timer happened to return values that fit in 16 bits. Also, your handle is very appropriate for this comment.

Comment: 0x12 - 0xE0 = 0xFFFFFF32 which is the incorrect answer if this were an 8 bit counter but (0x12 - 0xE0)&0xFF = 0x32 which is the correct answer, you have to ALWAYS mask if you want to use a free running timer to measure time by subtracting end from beginning for an up counter or beginning minus end for a down counter.Sometimes you can take a shortcut if you know the variables being used and instructions being generated are doing the masking for you otherwise you have to explicitly add the mask.If you optimize then you can always apply the mask and the optimizer will remove it as needed.

Comment: @old_timer That makes sense, I blame confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Newer ARM Cortex-M3/4/7 devices provide a register called CYCLECOUNTER, which can be often inspected in a debugger even without using any additional timer/counter and without adding any instrumentation to the code. The technique is described for example in the IAR AppNote "How to measure execution time with CYCLECOUNTER" at:

https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/how-to-measure-execution-time-with-cyclecounter/